# Definite integral of trigonometric function, any shortcuts?

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral question was 
$$\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} (\cos3x+\sin2x)(-\sin2019x+\cos3x) \,dx$$
Which could be made into a sum like this:
$$\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} \frac12\cos6x+\frac12+\frac12\sin5x-\frac12\sin{x}+\frac12\cos2021x-\frac12\cos2017x-\frac12\sin2022x-\frac12\sin2016x\,dx$$
Then I got all of this:
$$\frac{1}{12}\sin 6x+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{10}\cos5x+\frac{1}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{4044}\cos2022x+\frac{1} {4032}\sin2016x-\frac{1}{4034}\sin2017x+\frac{1}{4042}\sin2021x$$
Just to realise that the integral evaluates to $2\pi$
(I'm sorry I've just been introduced to integration, I'm learning it by myself. Not learnt yet from school.)
I've noticed that the integral of sin and cos parts all equalled zero, is it always the case? If so, what is the proof? Is making those parts equal zero the correct shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've noticed that the integral of sin and cos parts all equalled zero, is it always the case? If so, what is the proof?

Since you're integrating over an interval which is symmetric with respect to the origin, integrals of *odd functions* will evaluate to $0$ so that covers all the sines. For the cosines, note that:
$$\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} \cos(nx) \,\mbox{d}x=\frac{2\sin(2\pi n)}{n}$$
which is equal to $0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So you are right that you can discard all terms of the form $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ and only one term is left with a non-zero contribution:
$$\tfrac12\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} {\small \color{red}{\cos6x}\color{blue}{+1}\color{red}{+\sin5x-\sin{x}+\cos2021x-\cos2017x-\sin2022x-\sin2016x}}\,\mbox{d}x$$